# Consume Https Soap web service in ASP.NET Core 5

Tags: web-services, soap, https, asp.net-core-5.0

I have an HTTPS soap web service that has a certificate.

Firstly, I install that certificate as "local machine" in "Trusted Root Certification Authorities".

Then, I can connect to it and add a reference to it in the .NET Framework project.

**But** I have a problem when trying to consume it in the ASP.NET Core5 project. When I try to add it as a "WCF Web Service Reference", I got this error:

> An error occurred while attempting to find services at 'https://15.5.36.23/yxxx/soap/yyyy?wsdl'.
> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

I use Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2019 V16.10.2.

How can I fix it?

Thanks